# Discord.py Give role if member customstatus contains hi

Tags: discord, discord.py

Im working on a Loop that checks every 5 seconds if user Status contain "hi" if so it should give the user a role.
I dont really know how to do it, But maybe someone can help.

My code:

```py
#Here is a little base for the Command i asked...
#I hope it can help you
@tasks.loop(seconds=15)
async def status_role():
    if "hi" in ???.lower()
    #here comes the code
    #(Idk what the code is so i asked you guys :D)
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.server.roles, name="Friendly dude")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your new error, you're getting an `IndexError` because one of your members doesn't have an activity set, so `activities[0]` doesn't exist. Use an `if-statement` to check this. To see if a `tuple` is empty, you can just do `if tuple` (as empty lists/tuples are `falsy`), so the code below should solve that:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=15)
async def status_role():
    guild = client.get_guild(your guilds id) 
    role = get(guild.roles, name='Friendly dude') 
    for member in guild.members:
        if member.activities and 'hi' in member.activities[0].name.lower():
            await member.add_roles(role)
```

In addition to the fragment in the answer above.

EDIT: Apparently you didn't get my above ^ sentence saying it was meant to be combined with the other answer, so I've edited my answer & combined it myself. This *should* be the correct answer to your question.

Comment: I edited my code to
```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def status_role():
    for member in guild.members:
        if member.activities and 'hi' in member.activities[0].name.lower():
            await member.add_roles(role)
``` but it still dont works sorry im new to python :D

Comment: Unhandled exception in internal background task 'status_role'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lequi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\Programs\Clipox\ClipoxMain\main.py", line 134, in status_role
    for member in guild.members:
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined

Comment: I said "in addition to the code answer above" - the "guild" var is defined in that answer. You should replace the list comprehension ([await member.add_roles...]) there with my answer. I've edited my answer to contain the entire thing now.

Comment: My code
```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def status_role():
    guild = bot.get_guild(722571225544785930)
    role = get(guild.roles, name='susdel')
    for member in guild.members:
        if member.activities and 'hi' in member.activities[0].name.lower():
            await member.add_roles(role)

Comment: Unhandled exception in internal background task 'status_role'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lequi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\Programs\Clipox\ClipoxMain\main.py", line 137, in status_role
    if member.activities and 'hi' in member.activities[0].name.lower():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: That means the activity has no name, you can avoid it the same way as above (with an if-statement). For future reference - if something is `None` just `print()` it to see what comes out so you can identify the problem. Try `print()`ing the `Activity` as well to see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `member.activities`. This will return you a list of member's activities. As far as I know, you can get custom status with `member.avtivities[0].name`. This'll return you a string of member's custom activity.

Also, you can't use `ctx.message.author`. You need to iterate through members in the guild to check every one of their's activity.

So you can simply do:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=15)
async def status_role():
    guild = client.get_guild(your guilds id) 
    role = get(guild.roles, name='Friendly dude') 
    [await member.add_roles(role) for member in guild.members if 'hi' in member.activities[0].name.lower()]
```

**EDIT**

There're some updates about `Intents` in the discord.py 1.5.x. You need to define it before defining `client = discord.Bot(prefix='')` to get guilds, channels etc.

```py
import discord
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

**EDIT 2**

If member has no status, it'll return an empty tuple, that's why you get `IndexError`. To prevent this, you can add a simple if block to your code.

```py
async def status_role():
    guild = client.get_guild(your guilds id) 
    role = get(guild.roles, name='Friendly dude') 
    [await member.add_roles(role) for member in guild.members if member.activities[0] and 'hi' in member.activities[0].name.lower()]
```

Comment: Hmmm, i tryed it but it didnt work the error cam out is Bot is Ready : Clipoxmain
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'status_role'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lequi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\Programs\Clipox\ClipoxMain\main.py", line 136, in status_role
    role = get(guild.roles, name='susdel')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'

Comment: What's your discord.py version?

Comment: Im using 1.5 is there a newer?

Comment: Still a error in code cant send it here because to long....

Comment: You should add this to your post instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Nurqm No, it won't. If-statements go left to right, and you're checking if it actually exists as the second condition, meaning it will still error on the first one. You should `first` check if `member.activities` is not empty, and `then` check it's contents. Your answer is also wrong (it won't return `None` as `activities[0]`, but it will return an empty tuple instead for `activities` in general). If it was `None` it would be a NoneType exception, not an `IndexError`. Yours will still cause an IndexError no matter what as you're still trying to get the first element out of it to check.

Answer (score 0):

Still same error

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'status_role'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lequi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\Programs\Clipox\ClipoxMain\main.py", line 136, in status_role
    [await member.add_roles(role) for member in guild.members if 'hi' in member.activities[0].name.lower()]
  File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\Programs\Clipox\ClipoxMain\main.py", line 136, in <listcomp>
    [await member.add_roles(role) for member in guild.members if 'hi' in member.activities[0].name.lower()]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```